# Delete subsite in SharePoint 2010 programmatically

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I have a requirement to delete subsite of a site collection of SharePoint 2010.
I have have two options 1. using SharePoint Object Model 2. Front Page Method.

Any idea which option is better or what is different between two?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They result in the same outcome. The UI calls the underlying commands in the object model anyway. Go with whichever method you're more comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

In **powershell**, type the following:

```
Remove-SPWeb "http://ursite/" -Confirm:$false
```